# Neo4j query node property.

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have database with entities person (name,age) and project (name).
can I query the database in cypher that specifies me it is person or project?

for example consider I have these two instances for each :

Node (name = Alice, age= 20)
Node (name = Bob, age = 31)

Node (name = project1)
Node (name =  project2)

-I want to know, is there any way that I just say project1 and it tells me that this is a project.

-or I query Alice and it says me this is a person?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should use node labels (like `Person` and `Project`) to represent node "types".

For example, to create a person and a project:

```
CREATE (:Person {name: 'Alice', age: 20})
CREATE (:Project {name: 'project1'})
```

To find the project(s) named 'Fred':

```
MATCH (p:Project {name: 'Fred'})
RETURN p;
```

To get a collection of the labels of node `n`, you can invoke the `LABELS(n)` function. You can then look in that collection to see if the label you are looking for is in there. For example, if your Cypher query somehow obtains a node `n`, then this snippet would return `n` if and only if it has the `Person` label:

```
.
.
.
WHERE 'Person' IN LABELS(n)
RETURN n;
```

[UPDATED]

If you want to find all nodes with the `name` property value of "Fred":

```
MATCH (n {name: 'Fred'})
...
```

If you want to find all relationships with the name property value of "Fred":

```
MATCH ()-[r {name: 'Fred'})-()
...
```

If you want to match both in a single query, you have many ways to do that, depending on your exact use case. For example, if you want a cartesian product of the matching nodes and relationships:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (n {name: 'Fred'})
OPTIONAL MATCH ()-[r {name: 'Fred'})-()
...
```

Comment: @Eli You may want to review the [Cypher reference card](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/), with emphasis on the Labels section.

Comment: @InverseFalcon Thanks for the answer. My question is one level higher. For example, I query for a term 'X' and I want to know it is a property of a node or property of a relation. Then I know that the term 'X' is person or project. Does cypher has this ability?

Comment: @Eli: I (@cybersam) recently updated my answer, and it shows that you can use the `LABELS` function to find the labels of any node.

Comment: @Eli: You're asking for database-wide queries by property, and Neo4j is not built to handle that. You can check my answer for potential workarounds, but it sounds to me that what you want is something like ElasticSearch or SOLR, which specializes in inverted indexes and matching anything by string searches.

Comment: Still I think your assumption is that I know the type of node. I want something like this for querying term 'X' :

look all node, relations
where node.property = 'X' or relation.propety = 'X'
return node or relation

Comment: I do not want to write an encyclopedic treatise about all the ways to do that, so I have added one approach to my answer.

Comment: thanks for reply. as @InverseFalcon described maybe graph database is not good for such queries, since I don't have enough term to fill out the query requirement.

Answer (score 2):

So your use case is to search things by name, and those things can be of several types instead of a single type.

Just to note, in general, this is not what Neo4j is built for. Typically in Neo4j queries you know the type of the thing you're searching for, and you're exploring relationships between that thing (or things) to figure out associations or data derived from that.

That said, there are ways to do this, though it's worth going through the rest of your use cases and seeing if Neo4j is really the best tool for what you're trying to do

Whenever you're querying by a property, you either want a unique constraint on the label/property, or an index on the label/property. Note that you need a combination of a label and a property for this; you cannot blindly ask for a node with a property without specifying a label and get good performance, as it will have to do a scan of all nodes in your database (there are some older manual indexes in Neo4j, but I'm not sure if these will continue to be supported; the schema indexes are recommended by the developers).

There is a workaround to this, as Neo4j allows multiple labels on the same node. If you only expect to query certain types by name (for example, only projects and people), you might create a :Named label, and set that label on all :Project and :Person nodes (and any other labels where it should apply). You can then create an index on :Named.name. That way your query would be something like:

```
MATCH (n:Named)
WHERE n.name = 'blah'
WITH LABELS(n) as types
WITH FILTER(type in types WHERE type <> 'Named') as labels
RETURN labels
```

Keep in mind that you haven't specified if a name should be unique among node types, so it could be possible for a :Person or a :Project or multiple :Persons to have the same name, unsure how that affects what should happen on your end. If every named thing ought to have a unique name, you should create a unique constraint on :Named.name (though again, it's on you to ensure that every node you create that ought to be :Named has the :Named label applied on creation).

Comment: Thanks, your answer is right to the point. I was thinking that graph database is an option for such queries.  I am exploring the options to answer high level searches ( 'X' is person, location, project, etc.)  What do you suggest me to look for to answer such questions?

Comment: For example how the google knows that Tom Hanks is a person and return me back the detailed info of a person?

Comment: You may want to look at ElasticSearch, but in general I think you're looking for db solutions that use inverted indexes. As for Google, Google is not just using a single database solution, much of what they do is home-grown (and has introduced or inspired several current technologies). When it comes to textual matching without knowing context, dbs using inverted indexes are probably the best places to start. They also allow boosting of results based on various criteria, which sounds similar to what you're asking.

Comment: However, I should note that if you're looking to create a taxonomical system of some type (capturing info like "Bob is a Person", "a Lion is in the Cat family", and figuring out inferences), you could do with with Neo4j. There may be better solutions here (I think Prolog can do this well, likely other languages and technologies). In Neo4j you could do this by modeling your terms as nodes themselves (with a :Term label, maybe), and could point toward the actual :Person node (or whatever type of node) with data on it. But that involves capturing your key words as nodes. May not be the best fit.

Comment: sorry for many question and thanks for detailed answers. As you described above how does the taxonomy answer these question you mentioned in graph database  ("Bob is a Person", "a Lion is in the Cat family"). Can you give me detail like how to query a sample database with different types of entities that might exist

If I understood your example, this means I consider every term as node, in that case I have to search all nodes to find answer to a question like this : (Bob is a Person).

Comment: Almost got it, except those nodes you would search upon would be of a certain label that you ONLY use for this kind of a search, such as :Term, with an index on its 'name' property. That way your searches would only be restricted to :Term nodes and not every node in the db. Each :Term node could have a relationship pointing to a thing that they could describe. Really this is more like how you would implement a tagging system and a search-by-tags, and its horribly manual in its construction. It's an okay fallback, but best to search for a technology of better fit.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I find out that mapping the search terms to the entities in the ontology is itself complicated task. This paper is useful to check how the ontologies answers the questions. 

http://www.dai.ed.ac.uk/groups/ssp/members/openknowledge/Publications/Question%20answering%20on%20the%20real%20semantic%20web.pdf

As you mentioned an approach like inverted index (term -> entities in  ontologies) helps to translate the question and then use it to query database.